# How do I search my ArrayList for a specific persons details? How would i then edit or remove them?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I have an ArrayList which asks for user input then stores each employees details. How do I display everything stored in this ArrayList or search for a specific employee? How would I then edit or remove this employee from the ArrayList? I have two classes, one salesPerson - where I have all variables, setters, getters and constructors and salesPersonMain - where I have the prompting for user input, storing to an array etc.

I can add employees to the ArrayList and view them when I end the input loop.

```
public class salesPersonMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InputValidationException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<salesPerson> sPerson = new ArrayList<salesPerson>();

    while (true) {


        System.out.println("Enter id (press 'q' to quit): ");
        String temp = input.nextLine();
        if (temp.equals("q")) break;

        int id = Integer.parseInt(temp);

        System.out.println("Enter first name:");
        String firstName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter last name:");
        String lastName = input.nextLine();


        //save in array list
        sPerson.add(new salesPerson(id, firstName, lastName));

    }
    for (salesPerson salesPerson : sPerson) {
        System.out.println(salesPerson);
       }
    }
 }
```

The salesPerson class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class salesPerson{
    //create variables for sales person
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public salesPerson() {

    }

    //Setters and getters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) throws InputValidationException {
        if (firstName.matches("\\p{Upper}(\\p{Lower}){2,20}")) {
        } else {
            throw new InputValidationException();
        }
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)throws InputValidationException {
        if (lastName.matches("\\p{Upper}(\\p{Lower}){2,20}")) {
        } else {
            throw new InputValidationException();
        }
        {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }



    public void setCurrentCarMake(String currentCarMake) throws InputValidationException {
        if (currentCarMake.matches("(\\p{Alpha}{2,14})")) {
        } else {
            throw new InputValidationException();
        }
        {
            this.currentCarMake = currentCarMake;
        }
    }

    public String getCurrentCarModel() {
        return currentCarModel;
    }

    public void setCurrentCarModel(String currentCarModel) throws InputValidationException {
        if (currentCarModel.matches("(\\p{Alnum}{1,10})")) {
        } else {
            throw new InputValidationException();
        }
        {
            this.currentCarModel = currentCarModel;
        }
    }



    //create constructor
    public salesPerson(int id, String firstName, String lastName) throws InputValidationException {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + ", " + firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to search for/remove by? Right now the question is too broad to have an answer for. Including the salesPerson class would also be helpful.

Comment: If a salesPerson leaves the company, I'd like to search for them and remove them from the ArrayList. I intend to have a customer class so i'd like to be able to make changes to customer details, such as phone number.

Comment: If you intend on editing/removing items regularly, I would recommend using some sort of `Map` with the key being the salesPerson's ID, so you have O(1) access, and then just need to do use the [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) methods to do everything you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you have tried will take care of searching part in `List Of SalesPerson Object` and display correcting. You can do little more modification like below code to handle remove part as well.

**SalesPersonMain.java**

```
public class SalesPersonMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<SalesPerson> sPerson = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(); //List will fail in case of remove due to ConcurrentModificationException

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter id (press 'q' to quit): ");
        String temp = input.nextLine();
        if (temp.equals("q")) break;

        int id = Integer.parseInt(temp);

        System.out.println("Enter first name:");
        String firstName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter last name:");
        String lastName = input.nextLine();
        sPerson.add(new SalesPerson(id, firstName, lastName));

    }
    //Search
    System.out.println("Enter String to search & display");
    String searchString = input.nextLine();
    for (SalesPerson salesPerson : sPerson) {
        if(salesPerson.search(searchString)!=null){
            System.out.println(salesPerson.toString());
        }
    }
    //Remove
    System.out.println("Enter String to search & remove");
    searchString = input.nextLine();
    for (SalesPerson salesPerson : sPerson) {
        if(salesPerson.search(searchString)!=null){
            System.out.println(salesPerson.toString()+" is removed from the List");
            sPerson.remove(salesPerson);
        }
    }
    //Display All
    System.out.println("Final List : ");
    for (SalesPerson salesPerson : sPerson) {
        System.out.println(salesPerson.toString());
    }
}
```

}

**SalesPerson.java**

```
public class SalesPerson {

public SalesPerson(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

Integer id;
String firstName;
String lastName;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{" +
            "'id':" + id +
            ", 'firstName':'" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", 'lastName':'" + lastName + '\'' +
            '}';
}

public SalesPerson search(String search){
    if(firstName.matches("(.*)"+search+"(.*)") || lastName.matches("(.*)"+search+"(.*)")){
        return this;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Try the above code and hope you get the idea where to change what more.

Comment: So how would I go about the code for removing on the SalesPerson class?

Comment: Look what I understand from your question that given the List of SalesPerson object you want to remove one depending on some search. Same what I tried explain check the comment line `//Remove` in main class. If you want something else then elaborate more what remove you mean here ? Also, why don't take try yourself the code I wrote above and see if covers your scenario.

Comment: I have tried the code you gave, it seems to work until i have removed one salesperson, then i display the arraylist again and they are still there. How do I remove them and then display the updated arraylist?

Comment: Ya @JayMac now I have modified the code (there was typo inside remove code) to handle remove use-case. Read the about ConcurrentModificationException part to get why remove will fail. Now try you should able to get your working final list.

Comment: The remove is working, but I cannot view the final list as I am getting the ConcurrentModificationException error instead

Comment: How do I avoid this in order to remove the salesperson from the array list and then display the new arraylist?

Comment: Yes for same reason I was using `CopyOnWriteArrayList<SalesPerson> sPerson instead of List<SalesPerson>` check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a salesPerson class such as:

```
public class salesPerson {


    private int id;
    private String firstName, lastName;

    public salesPerson() {}

    public salesPerson(int id, String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
```

}

You can do something like this to search for a specific to remove:

```
        int searchIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sPerson.size(); i++) {
        salesPerson currentPerson = sPerson.get(i);
        //Prints current person
        System.out.println(currentPerson.getId() + " " + currentPerson.getFirstName() + " " + currentPerson.getLastName()); 
        if (currentPerson.getId() == 40) //Change 40 and getId to whatever you want to search for
        {
            searchIndex = i;
        }
    }
    //The remove is outside the loop because you don't want to change the index during the loop or you might run into problems
    sPerson.remove(searchIndex);
    }
```

You can edit this to search for multiple values or throw it into a method with a parameter for search value etc.